# Present participle of intransitive verbs

Tags: meaning, word-usage, participle

Usually the present participle has an active meaning and the past participle has a passive meaning.
However the past participle of intransitive verbs has an active meaning:

> Der Lehrer, in Berlin angekommen, war 25 Jahre alt.

If the past participle of intransitive verbs convey the active meaning, then how is it different from the present participle?

> Der Lehrer, in Berlin ankommend, war 25 Jahre alt.

Other related examples:

> Der angekommene/ankommende Lehrer.
>
> Das gesungene/singende Mädchen.

I feel both are correct but the past participle implies that the verb *kommen/singen* took place sometime before while the present participle implies a simultaneous action with other actions mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in general.

> Der Lehrer, in Berlin angekommen, war 25 Jahre alt.

*The teacher, **arrived** in Berlin, was 25 years old.*

It just happened a few days before or so.

> Der Lehrer, in Berlin ankommend, war 25 Jahre alt.

*The teacher, **arriving** in Berlin, was 25 years old.*

It's happening in that very moment.

That's the corner case in which the gerund and the present participle fall together and the only occassion in which German has "something like a gerund".

> Singend lief sie durch den Park.
>
> Die Zeitung gelangweilt durchblätternd saß er auf der Bank.

If you think about it *singend* and *durchblätternd* answer the question **how**, so it's clearly a present participle (adjective/adverb).

---

> Der angekommene/ankommende Lehrer (**ist** angekommen).

*The teacher who arrived a short while ago/is arriving just now.*

But that's again one of the verbs that build their perfect tense with *ist*.

> Das singende Mädchen (**hat** gesungen).

*The girl who sings just now.*

The past participle makes no sense here. It's songs that are sung, not persons.

> Das gesungene Lied (**ist** gesungen (worden)).

*The song which has been sung a while ago **or** is sung just now.*

Comment: I also felt that the past participle *gesungen* makes no sense so I put it deliberately just to be sure. My thought was that *whether really all past participles of intransitive verbs  can have an active meaning* and *singen* as you know can be both transitive or intransitive, so if I am talking here about the intransitive *singen*, its past participle will still not have an active meaning.

Comment: I beg your pardon? Did you mean *past participle*?

Comment: Ah, yes.. sorry

Comment: For transistive verbs, the past participle is passive, yes. For intransitive verbs, this makes no sense as there is no object which could become the subject. You need to use *es* or *man* then. *Man ist angekommen.* And this is indistiguishable from perfect tense.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how's *angekommen* different from *gesungen* in *Der angekommene/gesungene Lehrer* if both verbs can be intransitive? Why is the first right but the second wrong?

Comment: It *can* be. Not *it is*. In the passive voice, only the transitive form makes sense and anyone would understand it's transitive.

Comment: That is my point from the beginning, and that is why I put the *singen* example in the first place. I felt that not *all* past participles of supposedly intransitive verbs can be understood to have an active meaning.

Comment: I think I need another row of examples then. It's hard to follow your reasoning.

Comment: We can say for example *Der angekommene Lehrer* and it makes sense but not *Der gesprungene/gesprochene Lehrer* although *kommen, springen, sprechen* are all intransitive. Only the past participle of *kommen* but not *sprechen, springen* is understood to have an active meaning.

Comment: *Der vom Zehnmeterbrett gesprungene Lehrer ist wohlauf.* Perfectly valid.It's also an intransitive verb. You cannot *springen* an object.

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work for *singen* is you cannot *sing* persons. That simple.

Comment: That makes sense. Can we also say *Der gesprochene Lehrer* to mean the teacher who just talked, like we can say *Der angekommene Lehrer* to mean the teacher who just arrived?

Comment: No. That doesn't make sense either. You can *talk to* persons, and *talk about* persons, but not *talk* persons. *To talk to* is *ansprechen* and *to talk about* is *besprechen*. Also, *sprechen* can be transitive.

Comment: *Sprechen* is a bad example because it can be transitive. Apart from this, using the perfect participle in an active sense works only with verbs that form the perfect with *sein*.

Comment: @RHa Yes, I realized that. I also deduced that it works only with purely intransitive verbs that can't be transitive at all in any way. All my verbs *singen, sprechen, springen* can be transitive or intransitive, but *ankommen* is always intransitive.